# stop execution of python script by user command?

Tags: python

One of my data analysis application I am using Brute force search method  for finding similar patterns, the possible conditions will be  millions.

For better performance  all the results are store in the memory and will write into database every hours.

But now I can't stop the application in middle, So how i can give a exit command(like a command or shortcut key) to the application through command prompt, so it will write all the results into database from memory and call exit function (like `sys.exit()` ).

Can I accomplish this by using `argparse` or modules like `click`?. I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the user press Ctrl+C, and in your program catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception and write your output there.

Comment: You can also use CTRL + \ (backslash), which sends a `SIGQUIT`.